# Использование указателя на массив в качестве аргумента glBufferData

Tags: c, указатели, opengl

Проблема с glBufferData. Имеется рабочий код со статическим выделением памяти:

```
// In global scope
int terrainZ = 1500;
int terrainX = 1500;
GLfloat terrainVertices[terrainZ * terrainX * 18];

// Generating flat terrain. Fast & dirty
int index = 0;

for (int z = 0; z < terrainZ; z++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < terrainX; x++) {
        terrainVertices[index + 0] = x;
        terrainVertices[index + 1] = 0.0f;
        terrainVertices[index + 2] = z;

        terrainVertices[index + 3] = x + 1.0f;
        terrainVertices[index + 4] = 0.0f;
        terrainVertices[index + 5] = z;

        terrainVertices[index + 6] = x + 1.0f;
        terrainVertices[index + 7] = 0.0f;
        terrainVertices[index + 8] = z + 1.0f;

        terrainVertices[index + 9] = x;
        terrainVertices[index + 10] = 0.0f;
        terrainVertices[index + 11] = z;

        terrainVertices[index + 12] = x + 1.0f;
        terrainVertices[index + 13] = 0.0f;
        terrainVertices[index + 14] = z + 1.0f;

        terrainVertices[index + 15] = x;
        terrainVertices[index + 16] = 0.0f;
        terrainVertices[index + 17] = z + 1.0f;

        index += 18;
    }
}

GLuint terrainVAO = 0, terrainVBO = 0;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &terrainVAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &terrainVBO);

glBindVertexArray(terrainVAO);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, terrainVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(terrainVertices), terrainVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat) * 3, (GLvoid*) 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); // layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPosition;

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);

...

glBindVertexArray(terrainVAO);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, sizeof(terrainVertices) / sizeof(GLfloat) / 3);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Теперь код с динамическим выделением памяти:

```
// In function
int terrainZ = 1500;
int terrainX = 1500;
size_t terrainSize = terrainZ * terrainX * 18 * sizeof(GLfloat);

Glfloat* terrainVertices = malloc(terrainSize);
if (terrainVertices == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed\n");
    return;
}

// Generating flat terrain. Fast & dirty
int index = 0;

for (int z = 0; z < terrainZ; z++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < terrainX; x++) {
        terrainVertices[index + 0] = x;
        terrainVertices[index + 1] = 0.0f;
        terrainVertices[index + 2] = z;

        terrainVertices[index + 3] = x + 1.0f;
        terrainVertices[index + 4] = 0.0f;
        terrainVertices[index + 5] = z;

        terrainVertices[index + 6] = x + 1.0f;
        terrainVertices[index + 7] = 0.0f;
        terrainVertices[index + 8] = z + 1.0f;

        terrainVertices[index + 9] = x;
        terrainVertices[index + 10] = 0.0f;
        terrainVertices[index + 11] = z;

        terrainVertices[index + 12] = x + 1.0f;
        terrainVertices[index + 13] = 0.0f;
        terrainVertices[index + 14] = z + 1.0f;

        terrainVertices[index + 15] = x;
        terrainVertices[index + 16] = 0.0f;
        terrainVertices[index + 17] = z + 1.0f;

        index += 18;
    }
}

GLuint terrainVAO = 0, terrainVBO = 0;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &terrainVAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &terrainVBO);

glBindVertexArray(terrainVAO);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, terrainVBO);

// THE PROBLEM IS HERE
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, terrainSize, terrainVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
// glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, terrainSize, &terrainVertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat) * 3, (GLvoid*) 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); // layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPosition;

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);

...

glBindVertexArray(terrainVAO);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, terrainSize / sizeof(GLfloat) / 3);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

В этом случае ничего не рисуется. Где я ошибся?

Answer (score 0):

> Где я ошибся?

Я не знаю библиотеку, которую Вы используете, но обратите на внимание на второй параметр при вызове функции *glBufferData*:

```
// Первоначальный вариант:
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(terrainVertices), terrainVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Переработаный вариант:
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, terrainSize, terrainVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Я думаю, что если просто вставить печать значения этого параметра перед вызовом функции *glBufferData* в обоих вариантах программы, то ситуация прояснится. Мне кажется, что именно в расчёте размера массива у Вас есть ошибка.